# java mysql connector, CLASS_PATH

Tags: java

My `CLASS_PATH` entry in `.bashrc` is this:

```
CLASS_PATH=.:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
export CLASS_PATH
```

`echo $CLASS_PATH` shows

```
.:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
```

But the problem is when I execute the java program using `-cp (path to jar file)`, it works, but when I execute without `-cp`, it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I found the answer. I have put CLASSPATH variable as CLASS_PATH in .bashrc. Problem solved.